# Exception thrown while inserting record in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created an application in which data can be stored in a database. This database is a SQL Server based database which has been added to the C# solution in Visual Studio.

Until a few tests ago, everything worked fine. Now, when I want to add a new record to one of the tables, the next exception is thrown.

[image]

I do not understand what is wrobg. First I thought a connection with the database is the problem. However that cannot be the case since tables are still selected and all records are still available. The problem only occurs when I want to add a record to one of the tables.

Does someone know what is wrong and what a possible solution could be?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

The error says `String or binary data would be truncated`, which indicates one of the records you are trying to insert has string or binary data which exceeds the maximum size allowed by one of the columns defined in your database table.

For example, let's say your SQL table has a column defined as VARCHAR(10), which means it can hold up to 10 characters. If you try to insert a string that has more than 10 characters into this column, you would get this error.